# Что означают звездочки при вызове функций в python?

Tags: python

Пример:
print(*name_of_func())
Всем спасибо!

Comment: https://tproger.ru/translations/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=unpacking#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: вот тут хорошо объясняет https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJJ9wwzgJCA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.При вызове функции можно использовать оператор * для распаковки итерируемого объекта в аргументы вызова.

2.При определении функции можно использовать * , чтобы собрать переменное количество позиционных аргументов, переданных в функцию. Они помещаются в кортеж.
И так далее.

Подсмотрел [тут](https://tproger.ru/translations/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/).

В случае `print(*name_of_func())`, верен первый вариант.